# Monthly calendar

Tags: c#

I am new to C# is know some visual basic but I don't know C#. Now my question is I have a monthly calendar on my page and when someone selects the date and hits the submit button the date should appear in the label to the right. Here is a part of my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    label6.Text = monthCalendar1.Text;
}

private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label6.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
}
```

I am not understanding why it is not working.

Edit: What is not working is the label for the calendar when the user picks a date and click the submit button the date should go over to the label.

I have been here answering question and all i am asking is for someone to help me understand what I am doing wrong. And you guys want to down vote me..

Comment: monthCalendar1 is an instance of what class?

Comment: There is no `OnClick` event handler for `Label`.

Comment: @Tim: Yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx  Of course, is this WinForms, WPF, ASP? No idea.

Comment: @EdS. I see that now.  I was assuming ASP.NET, which doesn't have the OnClick event.

Comment: Have you looked at using the latest Ajax ToolKit?, free to download and easy to use. They have an extension calender which will meet your needs.

Comment: no i havent I am just got into C#

Comment: @snorris, I had edited your question and removed some unnecessary details(I think). But it seems you added them again. What, for ex, `label1.Text = textBox1.Text;` contributes to your question.

Comment: ok it didnt it was part of the code but I re-edit it

Comment: I suggest reading [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for some hints on how to write a question that can be answered. There isn't anywhere near enough information here for anyone to spot the flaws in what you're doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things we need to know:

- How is your UI laid out? Maybe post a picture and indicate where `label6` is.
- Any exceptions?
- What exactly happens when you click on your button? (Not working is not descriptive enough. Tell exactly what changes.)

My research: `monthCalendar1` is likely `System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar`. `MonthCalendar.SelectionStart` should be valid at any time, as long as it's between `MinDate` and `MaxDate`. What I don't get is if the label is your garden variety, why wouldn't the label show?

Other note: If there's a button to change the label, there's no point having a click handler on the label, and vice versa.

Comment: Label 6 is right beside the month calendar. The label6 I have up top the first label six is under the Private void button1_click and the second one is under private void label6_click. The selected date from the calendar control when the user clicks the button. That date needs to go over to the label to be shown. And what do you mean having a clock handler on the label?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a `Label` nested under a function? If so, it won't show on your `Form`. Your labels need to be defined within your form for it to show up. If you're referring to where `label6` is referenced, I can see it from your code snippet. And I said "click handler", not "clock handler" I'm referring to `label6_Click()`, which is unnecessary if you already have a button doing the same thing.

Comment: You could try to place some dummy code that changes your label text to some constant so you can check if it's your calendar or your label that's not working. Try replacing the body of `button1_Click()` with that code. Maybe like `label6.Text = "sample";`. Then make sure the initial text of your label is something different. Test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to define what "not working" means, but this is obviously wrong:

```
label3.Text = radioButton1.Text;
label3.Text = radioButton2.Text;
label3.Text = radioButton3.Text;
```

May as well just write:

```
label3.Text = radioButton3.Text;
```

But really, you need to work on your question and give us more detail.  As it stands no one could hope to make sense of it.

Comment: What is not working is the label for the calendar when the user picks a date and click the submit button the date should go over to the label.

Comment: @snorris - what platform is this?  ASP.NET, Windows Form, MVC, WPF...? You need to handle the event on the Calendar control, not the label.  Clarify your platform and I'm sure Ed can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Put a debug on the Label6.text = line in Button1Click event handler, see if it's doing what you think it is. I suspect not....

Comment: @snorris: No no, is this ASP, WinForms, WPF?  They all target .NET, but they are different.

Comment: I would say ASP most likely, I use visual basic express C#.

Comment: @snorris - Are you writing a web or desktop application? When you compile what ends up in your bin directory?

Comment: There is a folder called debug and release

Comment: @snorris - And what are in those folders? You'll be looking for .exe or .dll files

Comment: @snorris:... please stop guessing.  I realize that these terms are all new to you, but we can't really help unless we know exactly what you are doing.  When you created this project you had to chose a platform, WinForms, Windows Presentation Foundation, or ASP.  Which did you chose?

Comment: OK I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.And the book I am reading is Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 Window Forms Application Development. I don't know what else to say that is all the information I have. And to M.Babcock there is no exe or .dll files there is nothing in the release folder and in the debugg is Application program debug application, MANIFEST file and another application

Comment: If i was able to I would upload and image to show you what I am talking about but I can't it wont let me